# C# find the smallest amount in box / field

Tags: c#, console

I have program code, it's working fine, except for a few lines, where program have to find the smallest value and print it.

I have string field  / box "fieldEvidence.WorkingYears". user have to write number between 0 and 40.
User can put max 10 values or less (for ten people). Program must write out in the console the lowest walue in "fieldEvidence.WorkingYears"
If the values are the same (lets say 2-times '30') program must write both.

I have some code for now but it's not working in the right way, what should i change?

```
    static void WorkingAge(Evidence[] fieldEvidence)
    {
        int maxYears = 40;
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldEvidence.Length; i++)
        {
            if (maxYears > fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears)
            {
                maxYears = fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears;
            }
        }
        //10 times for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (maxYears == fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears)
                counter++;
        }

        //if there is more than just one with the same value
        if (counter > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldEvidence.Length; i++)
            {
                if (maxYears == fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Working years:{0}, fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldEvidence.Length; i++)
            {
                if (maxYears == fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Working years:{0}, fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example
User input: 40, 30, 23, 14, 34
output: Working years:14

Example 2
User input: 40, 23, 14, 14, 34
output: Working years:14, 14

Comment: why cant you just use the counter to print maxYears

Comment: Why would you print `23` and not `14` ?

Comment: @Kaz, that's the problem the OP is having. It's not printing the min.

Comment: @mike The code prints 14 when I run it. Not sure I see the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use LINQ - its very simple:

```
var example = new[]{40,30,23,14,34}.Select(year => new Evidence(year)).ToList();
var lowestVal = example.Min(x => x.WorkingYears);
var result = example.Where(x => x.WorkingYears == lowestVal)
                    .Select(x => x.WorkingYears);
Console.WriteLine("Working years: " + string.Join(", ", result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void WorkingAge(Evidence[] fieldEvidence)
{
    // make a counter for the number of equal min's found
    int counter = 1;

    // start with min equal to the first age in the array
    int min = fieldEvidence[0];

    // loop through array to find a possible new min
    for (int i = 1; i < fieldEvidence.Length; i++) {
        // if value < min, set min to this value and reset counter to 1
        if (fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears < min) {
            min = fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears;
            counter = 1;
        }
        // if value equal to min, increase counter
        else if (fieldEvidence[i].WorkingYears == min)
            counter++;
    }

    // create your output string starting with the min
    string output = min.ToString();
    // loop "counter" times to add multiple identical mins to string
    for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
        output = output + ", " + min;
    } 

    // output the string
    Console.WriteLine("Working years: " + output);

}
```

Comment: Just dumping code isn't very helpful. Please explain what your code does.